# Port-forwarding through modem and router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I've epon 1ge+wifi modem+router that my ISP gave me and another Dlink DIR 600 router behind the modem with which my laptop is connected. I need to setup port forwarding for my pc i tried port forwarding from modem to router thn from router to pc but it is not working.

Setup right now:-

---

#### Epon 1GE+WIFI (Modem+Router)

**[It is handling the connection to ISP and Whole DHCP server]**
IP : 192.168.1.1
Subnet : 255.255.255.0
Mode : Route
DHCP : enabled

---

#### Dlink DIR 600

IP : 192.168.1.2
Subnet : 255.255.255.0
DHCP : none(it has WAN connection type option in Internet settings which is set to DHCP)

---

ISP ==> Epon 1ge+wifi(Modem+Router) ==> Dlink DIR 600(Router)(through LAN) and other devices(with wifi) ==> PC+other devices(through wifi)

**P.S. I used same subnet to overcome the Double NAT problem but i think it is still not resolved and I noticed all devices behind the router are showing public ip other than the ip of modem.**

what am i doing wrong?

should i set Dlink as DMZ in Modem?
or
should i connect Dlink on WAN port instead of LAN port?
or
the Setup is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The dir-600 has port marked "internet" (http://www.dlink.com/al/sq/products/dir-600-wireless-n-150-home-router), which you should use to connect it to the Epon.

Comment: i tried, but i had to enable dhcp in Dlink which gave my pc ip 192.168.0.2/254, I had read in other threads that it creates Double NAT problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this this way:

Router DLINK WAN (192.168.1.100) connected to modem EPON LAN (192.168.1.1)
Router DLINK LAN (192.168.0.1) connected to other devices using (DLINK) DHCP 192.168.0.X

Use DLINK Wifi for your devices
Disable EPON Wifi

In modem EPON open the port (i.e. 80) from outside and redirect it to DLINK 192.168.1.100

In DLINK open the same port (i.e. 80) from EOPN and redirect it to the computer/device you need to connect to Internet.

Hope this helps.